# Instantiate class in Jasmin

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, jasmin

I'm trying to instantiate a class in Jasmin like this:

```
new Ljava/lang/Object;
dup
invokespecial java/lang/Object/<init>()V
```

This does compile but the class vierifier complains:

"VerifyError: Call to wrong initialization method."

What's the correct way to instantiate a class?

Comment: I'm no jasmine expert but are you trying to build an instance of Object? that class is abstract and therefore you cannot initialize it directly

Comment: @JuanAlbertoLópezCavallotti: You mean this class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html ?
It's not abstract. You can safely call `new Object()` from Java and it compiles.

Comment: Indeed, it's not abstract. It's possible to instantiate it but I'm unsure about the syntax.

Comment: @oddin look at that, everyday you learn something new, I guess that it had no sense to me before to try and instantiate Object. Do you get the same error if you try to run the app?

Comment: Instantiating Object is common to use them for locks in synchronized blocks. And I actually get the error when I try to run the class. VerifyError is thrown at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahh, I found the f***ing problem:

The parameter of 'new' should be the plain qualified name of the type, not it's decorated name. I. e. instead of

```
new Ljava/lang/Object;
```

you should write:

```
new java/lang/Object
```

The working code is:

```
new java/lang/Object
dup
invokespecial java/lang/Object/<init>()V
```

Comment: Don't forget to choose the answer (even if it's yours :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `invokespecial java/lang/Object/()V`.

Comment: Wow, why not <init>()V? Btw, this gives me another error:
"Expecting to find object/array on stack."
The reference pushed by 'new' should be on the top of the stack, shouldn't it?